# Measure what part of a loop that is slow?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm looping through a dataset with a couple of thousand items in it like this.

```
    users.forEach(function(user){
        //List ALLTHETHINGS!
        listAllEverything(user)
        //Add gropings
        user.groupings = groupings.filter(function(grouping){
            return grouping.conditional(user)
        })
        //Add conversions to user, one per user.
        user.conversions = {}
        //for each conversionList
        conversionLists.forEach(function(conversionList){
            user.conversions[conversionList.name] = [];
            //for each conversion
            for (var i = conversionList.conversions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var conversion = conversionList.conversions[i]
                //test against each users apilog
                var converted = user.apilog.some(function(event){
                    return conversion.conditional(event);
                })

                if (converted){
                    //Lägg till konverteringen och alla konverteringar som kommer innan.
                    for (var i = i; i >= 0; i--){
                        user.conversions[conversionList.name].push(conversionList.conversions[i])
                    }
                    break;
                }
            };
        })
    })
```

I know this is not the most optimized code and I have some ideas how it can be improved. But i'm pretty new to these kinds of problems, so I'm not sure how I should prioritize. I know about console.time, which is useful but I want to use something that allows me to compound the time spent on each part of the forEach-loop, either a tool (I usually use chrome) or some debugging-method. Perferably something that doesn't effect the performance too much.

Comment: The process that you want to perform is called `profiling`. Just search Google for `JavaScript profiling`. Good luck!

Comment: You may want to post your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AndrewDunai, thanks I was looking in to that a bit, most js-profiling seem to be about browser-events or cpu requirements, I'm not sure my loop demands much cpu, I think it's just slow. but maybe those are always the same?

Comment: For one-off profiling like this, I often just do a divide and conquer / binary search: Put timers between the first half and second half, then each quarter, etc.  I didn't know about `console.time`.  That is pretty neat!

Comment: @Brandon I assume you have to accumulate the times in each timer for every loop, will this affect the result noticably?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Chrome you shoud check out the Timeline tab in your browsers DevTools - just hit the record button before running the loop and stop it once it's done. You will se a nice breakdown of everything that just happened and you will be mostly interested in yellow bars - they show JavaScript operations.

Please check out this [video presentation by Paul Irish about Performance Tooling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xx_dkv9DEY)

As you know, in Chrome or Firefox you can just wrap a piece of code with console.time (and console.timeEnd) and it will measure the speed of particular operation and print it in the console.

For example: to measure the time it takes for an entire loop to execute use:

```
console.time('For loop benchmark');
for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
// do some operations here
}
console.timeEnd('For loop benchmark');
```

But, if you want to measure each iteration you can parameterize the name of the log inside the loop so that you can name each specific operation the way you want:

```
for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
    var consoleTimeName = 'Measuring iteration no '+i+' which is doing this and that...';
    console.time(consoleTimeName);
    // do some operations here
    console.timeEnd(consoleTimeName);
}
```

Using it you can see for yourself how much faster simple *for* loop can be in comparsion to jQuery's *$.each* loop.

You can find more about this on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.time) and [developer.chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api). Please not that this is note a standarized, cross-browser compatibile feature and you should not be using it on a production website, since some browser like IE may throw you an error when they see it.